# looker custom visualization using echarts

Tags: javascript, looker

Am creating custom visualization and am using echarts for the visualization.

I have a source and everything but i am unable to make it work. Can anyone help in this how to achieve the below fiddle in looker custom visualization

```
import * as echarts from 'echarts';

var ROOT_PATH = 'https://echarts.apache.org/examples';

var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

myChart.showLoading();
$.getJSON(ROOT_PATH + '/data/asset/data/les-miserables.json', function (graph) {
    myChart.hideLoading();

    graph.nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        node.label = {
            show: node.symbolSize > 30
        };
    });
    option = {
        title: {
            text: 'Les Miserables',
            subtext: 'Default layout',
            top: 'bottom',
            left: 'right'
        },
        tooltip: {},
        legend: [{
            // selectedMode: 'single',
            data: graph.categories.map(function (a) {
                return a.name;
            })
        }],
        animationDuration: 1500,
        animationEasingUpdate: 'quinticInOut',
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Les Miserables',
                type: 'graph',
                layout: 'none',
                data: graph.nodes,
                links: graph.links,
                categories: graph.categories,
                roam: true,
                label: {
                    position: 'right',
                    formatter: '{b}'
                },
                lineStyle: {
                    color: 'source',
                    curveness: 0.3
                },
                emphasis: {
                    focus: 'adjacency',
                    lineStyle: {
                        width: 10
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    myChart.setOption(option);
});

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

demo [url](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph)

in the above snippet, they are passing json but in my requirement i need to fetch from selected dimensions or measures and I need to convert into looker custom viz

```
looker.plugins.visualizations.add({

  
});
```

Please do let me know any suggestions on this

Answer (score 0):

Inside the object you pass to `looker.plugins.visualizations.add`, the `updateAsync` method ( that you will use to generate the echart options and series ) is async, and it passes you a `done` callback to be called when you are ready.

So you can call your json, process the data and then `done()`